# My device overloops, conditions not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created simple web watch using tizen studio made for gear watch etc.

In this web watch I have 6 conditions. These conditions supposed to switch the background of the watch based on current time of day. I can say that it should be like phases of the day. So earlyMorning-morning-afternoon-earlyEvening-evening-night.

These conditions are loaded together with digital watch. It is the only way how I managed to get it to work. My problem is.

Night condition is not working and I dont know why, since it is the same condition as others for day for example. After night when watches should come back to 'day mode' it does not working as well. And after several days watches gets overlooped I guess.

js

```
window.onload = function() {
// TODO:: Do your initialization job

// variables for img transitions

// add eventListener for tizenhwkey
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59


    if(h === 0){
        h = 24;
    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("MyClockDisplay").textContent = time;

    // day1 starting

    if('10:00:05' <= time&&time < '16:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("day1").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("day2").style.opacity = "1";
    }   

    if('16:00:05' <= time&&time < '20:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("day2").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("day3").style.opacity = "1";
    }  

    if('20:00:05' <= time&&time < '23:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("day3").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("night1").style.opacity = "1";
    }   

    if('23:00:05' <= time&&time < '04:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("night1").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("night2").style.opacity = "1";
    }   

    if('04:00:05' <= time&&time < '06:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("night2").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("night3").style.opacity = "1";
    }  

    if('06:00:05' <= time&&time < '10:00:00')
    {
        document.getElementById("nigth3").style.opacity = "0";
        document.getElementById("day1").style.opacity = "1";
    } 

    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);  

}

showTime();

function showdate(){

    var d = new Date();
    var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = days[d.getDay()];
    }

showdate();

};
```

html

```
.clock {
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 30px;
/*   font-family: Orbitron; */
letter-spacing: 7px;
}

img {
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
height: 360px;
width: 360px;
transition: all 5s ease;
}

#components-main {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.showsPM {
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 28px;
 /*   font-family: Orbitron; */
 letter-spacing: 7px;
 }

.showsDate {
 position: absolute;
 top: 55%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 22px;
 /*   font-family: Orbitron; */
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 }
```

html

```
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>
            <div id="container">    


    <img id="day1" src="/images/day1.png" style="opacity: 0"/>   
    <img id="day2" src="/images/day2.png" style="opacity: 1"/>  
    <img id="day3" src="/images/day3.png" style="opacity: 0"/>  
    <img id="night1" src="/images/night1.png" style="opacity: 0"/>  
    <img id="night2" src="/images/night2.png" style="opacity: 0"/>  
    <img id="night3" src="/images/night3.png" style="opacity: 0"/>  

    <!--  <div id="backgroundNight" style="opacity: 0;"></div>-->

        <div id="MyClockDisplay" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
        <div id="date" class="showsDate"></div>     

</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Is there any better way how can I do something like that? Or do you see any mistakes in my code?

Comment: Is it possible the problem is just this typo: `document.getElementById("nigth3")`

Comment: @DanielBeck What do you mean?

Comment: I also see the script `js/main.js` included twice, than also some inline `onload="showTime()"` garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line `if('23:00:05' <= time&&time < '04:00:00')`
This test is never true because you are saying time should be more than 23 and less then 04.

The comparison operator does not know that 01 is later than 23. So you should turn the && into || (or) since these are both at the edge of the range:

```
if('23:00:05' <= time || time < '04:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this condition:

```
if('23:00:05' <= time && time < '04:00:00')
```

Let's assume it's 23:10, the first part of your condition is true, while the second one is not, which makes complete sense because 23 is not smaller than 4.

Change the condition to this:

```
if('23:00:05' <= time || time>='00:00:05' && time < '04:00:00')
```

This will make sure the condition is true if it's between 23-0 & 0-4.

Comment: So let's say. I start watch at 10:00 morning, it is gonna work all day but conditions from 04:00:05 not working anymore. Do you see any mistakes why it shouldnt work?

Comment: It is so wierd.

Answer (score 1):

This condition will never be true.

```
if('23:00:05' <= time&&time < '04:00:00')
{
    document.getElementById("night1").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("night2").style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Do this instead

```
if(('23:00:05' <= time&&time <= '24:59:59') || ('01:00:00' <= time&&time < '04:00:00'))
{
    document.getElementById("night1").style.opacity = "0";
    document.getElementById("night2").style.opacity = "1";
}
```